# NodeJS upload files 100% cpu usage

Tags: node.js, formidable, multer

I've tried two different libraries: [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for handling file upload in node and both of them use 100% CPU during upload.

Is it a common node problem? And how people deal with it in high concurrency environment?

Node version: `v0.10.36` (I've even tried other versions like *v0.11.x* or *v0.10.33*)

**Formidable example**

```
Picture.upload = function(user, req, cb) {
    var formidable = require('formidable')

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = "./uploads";
    form.maxFieldsSize = app.settings.uploadMaxSize * 1024 * 1024;
    form.maxFields = 1000;

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        cb(null, files);
    });
}
```

**Multer example**

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
       return filename+Date.now();
    },
    limits: {
       files: 1,
       fileSize: app.settings.uploadMaxSize * 1024 * 1024
    }
})); // after I process the file from req.files
```

File are uploaded as `multipart/form-data`.

I'm using [loopback](http://loopback.io/), but I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: Can you post a code example? Just a wild guess, maybe this is relevant https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/109 ?

Comment: I don't think it is related because my problem is with CPU not with memory usage. Anyway I've added two code snippets

Comment: can you try the following code?  `fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('public/images/' + filename))
            .on('close', function () {
                fs.unlink(filePath, function () {
                    callback(null, '/images/' + filename);
                });
            });` use this as a controller, in your upload endpoint.

Comment: I didn't understand how to test your snippet. Do you want to copy the file after it was uploaded? (so I have to place it in `form.parse`?)

Comment: Which operating system are you running node under that you experience this condition?

Comment: Are you sure that using 100% CPU is actually something to worry about? For example if this is on your test machine, and your test machine is doing nothing else, it's probably what should be happening. A better question might be: is this blocking the event loop? Did you test for that?

Comment: Are you processing this file at all after uploading it or just storing it on disk?

Comment: I think that on a high concurrency production environment, the solution is simply adding more CPU to the server. Sorry for that. Well, I'm working with uploads, too but without `multer` or `formidable`. Try it, too. It will be significantly faster.

Comment: @GabrielTomitsuka That's simply not the answer. There is an issue here. Adding more CPU's isn't at all _highly concurrent_, as you'd need account nearly an entire CPU for each upload, which is unrealistic in most scenarios.

Comment: Please provide details of any processing which take place after the file is uploaded, and possibly analyze CPU load without this post-processing. If you've already done so it might also be worth benchmarking to see if you're actually getting a significant performance loss. Other things that come to mind are that you might be running into problems due to hypervisor restrictions. Are you running this in a VM or bare metal? What OS(and kernel version). If you're using linux could you provide stats via mpstat?

Comment: I have just tested a vey simple file upload I have in a test app, and an 11M movie seems to make CPU move from about 3% to about 10% on an Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance. Not too scientific or statistically significant but maybe indicates it might be worth doing some more analysis as @tsturzi suggests? I was using express and Multer, but not using loopback. Also as others have I think suggested CPU usage needs to be interpreted carefully as mosts OS's manage load to make best use of available CPU (so may run low priority house keeping tasks when there is not much going on for example).

Comment: I also ran tests locally and was unable to reproduce your outcome. In my case I rarely saw CPU reach above 3%. I see the comment `// after I process the file from req.files` and I have a feeling that possibly you're processing the file after you upload it in the same thread of execution as your file upload. This could possibly cause blocking, in which I would recommend something like [kue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue) or some other method of moving logically intensive code to a worker node.

Answer (score -1):

In a high concurrency environment if a task makes the cpu reach 100% sadly node will [block](https://bitcartel.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/the-node-js-cpu-blocking-thing/). I assume uploading a file means the same thing as serving static assets. There is a lot of discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/jyYIYUEUBQw) about how nodejs is not suited for serving static content. Use nginx or apache instead.

Another solution is to delegate the upload to a worker process or queuing system. See [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) for example.

Comment: This is not true. The CPU percentage usage is based off of many things, and upload is almost all IO. 100% CPU will not always block. Only on logically intensive methods. It could in fact just represent a very full event-loop, which makes sense because multer uses streams. Queuing uploads doesn't make sense, you can't just queue the request to ZMQ and then reconnect the client to a worker. People queue things that are already uploaded in order to process them, like image manipulation.

Comment: I suppose I could, however I'd only do so if I had a good idea of exactly what was going on. Though obviously a simple task shouldn't be using 100% CPU regardless. What I was saying is that, if it were, this doesn't directly indicate blocking. Though its likely represents degraded performance.